# How can I remove a "Pending Task" from the Instructor dashboard in Open edX?

Tags: edx, openedx

I am trying to "Download a CSV of Problem Responses" in the Instructor dashboard's "Data Download" section in Open edX, but while doing this a task became stuck as a "Pending Task".

It has been like this for over 2 days, is there any way to delete the task?  I am unable to generate new problem responses until this pending one is completed.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the instructions on the Open edX wiki for [how to manually fail an instructor task](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SUST/pages/34013356/How+to+fail+an+instructor+task) from the Django Admin:

1. Get the task id you're going to fail from the instructor dashboard: courses.edx.org/courses//instructor
2. Go to the django admin panel, and click "Instructor tasks", which should be below "Instructor_Task"
3. Find the instructor task you want to fail
4. Set the Task state to "FAILURE" (all caps)
5. Set the Task output to "{}"
6. Set the Task key to "dummy_task_key"
7. Click Save

Answer (score 1):

You can view and manage any pending tasks started on the instructor dashboard using the Instructor Task admin view (e.g. https://myopenedx.example.com/admin/instructor_task/instructortask/).